# Tab navigator issue when calling an API

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i am stuck in a problem that is,

in my application one screen has a Tabbar component so i have used Tabnavigation from react-navigation.

so there is two tabs in that screen and both of that tabs have GET API for displaying data

so my main problem is when tab screen is open at that time both tabs file is calling API because of tabnavigator is in stack navigator.

So please help me to solve this issue.
i have to do like this::-

when i click on tab then after API will be call but here when the screen is arrive at that time both tabs call their API.

so please sort out this issue guys.

Comment: On what point of the component lifecycle do you make your API calls ? Could you maybe show some code ?

Comment: See i am calling the API on componentDidMount because the API is about GET so i just getting the data and display to the view in scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TabNavigator`'s [`lazy`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig) prop.

> **lazy** - Whether to lazily render tabs as needed as opposed to rendering them upfront.

This way your API call will happen only when you switch to that tab. The call will happen only on first switch though. You may need to add some logic to recall API on certain event or time to get the new data.

Comment: Okay but can you please share some code about how i used that lazy prop.

Comment: Hey there thanks a lot its very useful for me thank you again